# Diffeomorphism invariant scalars of a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g_{ab})$ be a Riemannian manifold. I know of the following scalars that one can construct them out of the metric and its derivatives:

1. Ricci scalar $R$
2. $R_{ab}R^{ab}$
3. $R_{abcd}R^{abcd}$

Are there more *independent* scalars that can be constructed or are all diffeomorphism invariant scalars functions of these?

What about $R_{ab}R_{cd}R^{acbd}$?

I am looking for a list of *independent* scalars such that any other scalar can be expressed as a function of scalars in the list.

Any relevent references are most welcome.

Comment: On searching about it on the internet, I came across [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carminati%E2%80%93McLenaghan_invariants)  and this [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063%2F1.529470).Though this is perhaps limited to 4 dimensions and Lorentzian metrics and does not settle the general question asked above.