# Scalar differential operator commuting with isometries

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

It is stated in various places that, in the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, a [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) which commutes with every isometries can be expressed as a polynomial of the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is for instance stated [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833517/is-every-scalar-differential-operator-on-m-g-that-commutes-with-isometries-a) in the broader context of Riemannian geometry.

I can't find a proof of this fact. Would you be able to point me to a document that proves it and/or to give me the key ingredients of the proof?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I was thinking, is there a way to use the Fourier transform (then restricting the set of functions on which we assume that the Laplacian and isometries are acting) to turn this into a form that would be provable using algebraic considerations? (e.g. we would require a polynomial P corresponding to the operator to depend only on $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$)

Comment: Are you assuming constant coefficients?

Comment: @Deane I actually realized I made this assumption in my answer, but the result should hold for coefficients as functions. I don't know if I can get the full result using my method...

Comment: @Weier the way you reduce to constant coefficients is that translations are also isometries of $\Bbb{R}^n$, so commuting with translations implies the coefficients must be constant (actually it’s equivalent).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Indeed... and that still works if I consider the full Poincaré group (the Lorentzian case seems a bit more tricky).

Answer (score 3):

*(Analysis is not my thing but after giving it some thought I think something like this will work — please correct me if I'm wrong)*

Let $D = P(D^1, ..., D^n)$ be a differential operator commuting with isometries.

In particular $D(f \circ g) = Df \circ g$ (*) for any [Schwartz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $f$ and isometry $g$.

Taking the Fourier transform $\mathfrak{F}$ we get (using the scaling property of the Fourier transform mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171462/fourier-transform-of-function-composition) for linear operators — I am omitting the determinant which will factor out):

$$
\mathfrak{F}(D(f \circ g)) = P \cdot \mathfrak{F}(f \circ g) = P \cdot \mathfrak{F}(f) \circ g^{-1} \\
\mathfrak{F}(Df \circ g) = F(D f) \circ g^{-1} = (P \cdot \mathfrak{F}(f)) \circ g^{-1}
$$

By (*) we get $P = P \circ g^{-1}$ (considering a $f$ such that the support of $\mathfrak{F}(f)$ is the whole real line).

The only polynomials $P(X_1, ..., X_n)$ which are invariant by all isometries are those which are functions of ${X_1}^2 + ... + {X_n}^2$ (we can show that it factors as $P - \lambda = Q \cdot ({X_1}^2 + ... + {X_n}^2)$ for some scalar $\lambda$ then the same for $Q$ etc. until we reach the degree of $P$).

Note that this should also work in the case of the Lorentz group and and the [d'Alembert operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert_operator).

Comment: this is very nice

Comment: This point is proved in Folland’s PDE book, and the Lorentzian case is left as an exercise.